# Limit Infinispan File Store Size

Tags: infinispan

I would like to cache very large amounts of data in an Infinispan 13 cache that uses passivation to the disk. I've accomplished this with the following configuration:

```
<persistence passivation="true">
  <file-store purge="true"/>
</persistence>
<memory storage="OFF_HEAP" max-size="1GB" when-full="REMOVE"/>
```

However, now I would like to set the maximum size for the file-store to i.e. 50GB and have the cache delete overflowing entries completely.

Is there a way to do this? I could not find any option to limit the size of a file-store in the documentation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to specifically limit the total size of the files stored. Depending upon your use case setting the `compaction-ratio` lower which should help free some space. https://docs.jboss.org/infinispan/13.0/configdocs/infinispan-config-13.0.html under `file-store`

You can use expiration though to remove entries after a given period of time. https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html#expiration_configuring-memory-usage This will remove those entries from the cache, which in turn would hit that compaction-ratio sooner to clean up old files.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
So, a setting like `max-size` or `max-entries` like for the memory part is not available for the file-store. Did I get that right?

We already have an expiry configured and I'm not too concerned with the exact size of the file-store. So the default `compaction-ratio` is fine.

What I would like to do is to make sure that the storage space that's consumed doesn't get completely out of hand if there is a spike in activity. But it seems that's not possible.

Comment: There is no specific setting to drop excess items. The main reasoning is because this causes data loss and we are trying to avoid that as a base line.

However, I would suggest you create an issue at https://issues.redhat.com/projects/ISPN or bringing it up for discussion at https://infinispan.zulipchat.com/ and this can be evaluated for inclusion moving forward.